# sxa custom boosting condition for dynamic value from cookie

Tags: sxa, content-search, rules-engine, sxa-search, boosting

We have a requirement where we want to boost results based on a value from a cookie/session. The items that contains the value from cookie in a  Certain field should be boosted. Hence the rule should be something as below.
"where field value contains this value from cookie"

I hope this should be done thru custom boosting condition, but not sure how the same can be done. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is how to configure it (when you will have your rule):
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/boost-search-results-for-sxa-site-queries.html
There are many resources on how to write a custom rule, for example:
http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.com/2014/03/cookie-based-sitecore-rule-conditions.html

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak Thanks for the suggestion, I am looking to implement something like "where field value contains this value from cookie".

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved by imitating existing rules. Works as expected.

```
        string storeVisited = CookieHelper.GetCookie("VisitedStore");

        WhenFieldAndQueryStringMatches<RuleBoostingContext> ruleCondition = args.RuleCondition as WhenFieldAndQueryStringMatches<RuleBoostingContext>;
        string operatorId = ruleCondition.OperatorId;
        string fieldName = ruleCondition.FieldName;
        if (operatorId.EqualsId(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Templates.IsEqualTo.Id))
            args.Predicate = (Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>>)(c => c[fieldName].Equals(storeVisited).Boost<bool>(args.Boost) || c.Name != string.Empty);
        else if (operatorId.EqualsId(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Templates.IsNotEqualTo.Id))
            args.Predicate = (Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>>)(c => !c[fieldName].Equals(storeVisited).Boost<bool>(args.Boost) || c.Name != string.Empty);
        else if (operatorId.EqualsId(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Templates.Contains.Id))
            args.Predicate = (Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>>)(c => c[fieldName].Contains(storeVisited).Boost<bool>(args.Boost) || c.Name != string.Empty);
        else if (operatorId.EqualsId(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Templates.StartsWith.Id))
            args.Predicate = (Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>>)(c => c[fieldName].StartsWith(storeVisited).Boost<bool>(args.Boost) || c.Name != string.Empty);
        else if (operatorId.EqualsId(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Templates.EndsWith.Id))
            args.Predicate = (Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>>)(c => c[fieldName].EndsWith(storeVisited).Boost<bool>(args.Boost) || c.Name != string.Empty);
        else if (operatorId.EqualsId(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Templates.IsCaseInsensitivelyEqualTo.Id))
            args.Predicate = (Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>>)(c => c[fieldName].Equals(storeVisited, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Boost<bool>(args.Boost) || c.Name != string.Empty);
        else if (operatorId.EqualsId(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Templates.IsNotCaseInsensitivelyEqualTo.Id))
            args.Predicate = (Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>>)(c => !c[fieldName].Equals(storeVisited, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Boost<bool>(args.Boost) || c.Name != string.Empty);
        else
            args.Predicate = (Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>>)(contentPage => true);
    }
```